# Load large audio files with just_audio

Tags: flutter, dart, audio-player, just-audio

I have developed music application in Flutter using [just_audio](https://pub.dev/packages/just_audio) and [just_audio_background](https://pub.dev/packages/just_audio_background). The music feature and controls are working fine, the only concern is when I am loading the playlist at that time I have at least 20 songs to load and they have a large duration. How can I reduce this loading time duration?

```
//Generating list
list.add(AudioSource.uri(
    Uri.parse(musicDetails!.trackFileUrl!),
        tag: MediaItem(
            id: currentSongIndex.toString(),
             album: musicDetails!.description ?? "",
             title: musicDetails!.title ?? "",
             artUri: Uri.parse(musicDetails!.coverImage ?? ""),
           ),
       )
);
//Adding entire list to playlist
final playlist = ConcatenatingAudioSource(children: list);
await player.setLoopMode(LoopMode.all);
await player.setAudioSource(playlist,initialIndex: currentSongIndex.value);
```

I want to change this approach for adding playlist in player. How can I achieve this?

Comment: May I ask which platform you are experiencing slow load times for?

Comment: I have developed application in Flutter and facing in android & iOS platform

Comment: The Android implementation was optimised to have much faster loading times than iOS, so if you're saying that you're even facing this problem in Android, please report it as a bug on the GitHub page.

Comment: Actually, I am adding 20 songs where each song has a time duration of 3 to 4hr and respective audio source size is significantaly large. For that any other approach available?

Comment: I'm trying to establish whether you're experiencing the problem on both Android and iOS or just iOS. Your first reply didn't directly confirm whether you experienced the problem on both platforms. Your second reply also didn't establish it. That's my limit, so I'll leave here and allow others to help you.

Comment: I appreciate your help, but I am asking for an approach to load a large source in the player. which means I am facing this issue on both platforms, which I already confirmed in first comment.

Comment: What exactly is the problem you're facing on Android?

Comment: I resolve this by adding few songs at a time, rather than entire playlist. Thank you.

Comment: But what was the exact problem that occurred on Android so that it can be fixed?

Comment: When I try to load 20 songs at a time, where each song has a large size ( Each song size is around 70MB). it took more time to load. This was the issue.

Answer (score 1):

The Android implementation supports an option called [useLazyPreparation](https://pub.dev/documentation/just_audio/latest/just_audio/ConcatenatingAudioSource-class.html) which actually defaults to true. This option loads each item just before the player gets up to it in playback rather than upfront all at once.

An implementation of this option for iOS is awaiting testing and is [described in this GitHub issue](https://github.com/ryanheise/just_audio/issues/294) on the `treadmill` branch.